# Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Validation of received messages enabled, but no signature found on message

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

Trying to setup a SP in shibboleth, when testing against a testIdP, I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add the attribute "signing" with value "true" to Shibboleth2.xml:

```
<ApplicationDefaults 
entityID="example.org" 
REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
signing="true">
```